# How to change the date in agendaView of FullCalendar javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using this great javascript [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) plugin.

I have to display a month calendar, and when a day is selected, show the agendaView next to it like so:
[image: Calendar]

In that example image, the user has clicked on July 1st, and I need the agendaView on the right to display for July 1st, but it always loads today's date.

Here is the code. You can see the commented code where I tried to set the visible range when the 'day' calendar (agendaView) is loaded, but that did not work. Currently at the end I'm trying to use the changeView function, but that also didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  var selectedDay = null;
  var selected = moment();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // options and callbacks here

    aspectRatio: 1.5,

    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

      // alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

      // alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

      // reset previously selected day's background color
      if (selectedDay !== null) {
        $(selectedDay).css('background-color', 'transparent')
      };
      // change the newly selected day's background color
      $(this).css('background-color', '#A5DC86');
      selectedDay = this;
      // selected = this.fullCalendar.moment();
      selected = this.date;

      $('#day').fullCalendar({
        // visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
        //   return {
        //     start: selected.date,
        //     end: selected.date.clone().add(1, 'days') // exclusive end
        //   };
        // },
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay', 
        header: {left: '', center: 'title', right: ''},
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotDuration: '00:60:00',
        scrollTime: '00:00:00'
      }),
      $('#day').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', selectedDay.date )
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that changeView expects a formatted date, so:

```
$('#day').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', date.format() )
```

is the solution.